# redirect PHP using specific time

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have 3 index files
 index1.php
 night.php
 weekend.php

I want to access night.php using redirect pages from index.php by using a specific time example: every hour 3.00pm index.php redirect to night.php and every hour 7.30am back again to the index.php page

please help !!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Mixing code to get the current time, code to compare it to your criteria, and code to do a redirect should do the trick.  What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this will help you!!!
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide'); //Sets the default timezone
$time = strtotime(date("h", time()));
if($time ==strtotime("15:20:00")){
    header("location: night.php");
    exit;
}
if($time==strtotime("7:30:00")){
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of PHP's `date` function to check the current time/date. To redirect to another file, just use the `header("Location: ..")` function to do a 302 redirect.

Here's a quick sample of what I could understand from your requirements description:

```
<?php

    $redirectLocation = '';

    $dayOfWeek = date('l'); // A full textual representation of the day of the week
    $weekendDays = array('Saturday', 'Sunday'); // Array of weekend days
    $currentTime = (date('G').date('i'))*1; // Get current time in the form of numbers

    // If is weekend, redirect to weekend.php
    if(in_array( $dayOfWeek, $weekendDays )) {
        $redirectLocation = 'weekend.php';
    }

    // Else handle weekday day time (7.30 - 15.00)
    else if( $currentTime >= 730 && $currentTime <= 1500 ) {
        $redirectLocation = 'index1.php';
    }


    // Else handle weekday evening time
    else {
        $redirectLocation = 'night.php';
    }

    // Do the redirecting
    header("Location: ".$redirectLocation);
    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Upvote and mark me as the Answer please!