# PHP redirects by countdown without updating

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

In short, I would like to redirect users at 16:00 to ex: breakout.php.
Wondering if i can do it without JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a meta-redirect tag and specify the number of seconds until the redirect

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=https://example.com/">
```

`content` parameter is the number of seconds. You can calculate the number of seconds between now and e.g. 16:00 with PHP and generate a correct value.

Comment: Thank you, let me be more precise.
Users are already on the web page ex: plenary session live, at 4 pm I would like to redirect them. 

So, you mean that on the page load, I have to calculate the remaining seconds and pass the value into the "content" ?

Comment: yes! You need to calculate the value with PHP when you generate the page. Another option is with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48656289/12716902) will help you!!!

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Adelaide'); //Sets the default timezone
$time = strtotime(date("h", time()));
if($time >= strtotime("16:00:00")){
    header("location: breakout.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: How would this do the job, if a visitor has loaded a page at 15:59?

Comment: @Teemu nothing, then this condition not work